# How to populate a MongoDB database for e2e testing effectively

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mocha.js, e2e-testing

I have set up my environments as described here: https://medium.com/developer-circles-lusaka/how-to-write-an-express-js-server-using-test-driven-development-921dc55aec07

This means I am using the config package to select an environment.

What I would like to do is (re-)populate the database before each test is performed. I am expecting this can be done using the beforeEach() hook Mocha provides (I am using Mocha as a test runner).

My question is to what is an effective way of loading a bunch of data into the database all at once (I am using Mongoose in case that makes a difference. I do not know if I can omit that when inserting)? Preferably this is done in a separated file from the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I do:

Drop the database completely in beforeEach. You can get access to mongodb instance on you mongoose connection like: `db.db.dropDatabase()`

Create preconfigured data objects for my domain and save them in a module that I import - simple JavaScript objects. So I have data like data.users.vader and data.users.luke, data.products.deathStar etc

In my tests, I use [chaihttp](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/) to hit routes with the data like:

```
let user = data.users.vader;
chai.request(server)
                    .post('/users')
                    .send(user)
                    .end((err, result) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return callback(err);
                        }

result.should.have.status(200);
                        result.body.status.should.eq(enums.status.success);
                        result.body.data._id.should.be.a('string');
                        result.body.data.name.should.eq(user.name);
                        result.body.data.email.should.eq(user.email);
```

Each unit test will drop the database and create the data needed. I start like this so that each test is independent.

You can also bulk load data using mongodb’s `batchWriteItem` later on.

I also create functions that can be called within unit tests that will bulk load data using `batchWriteItem` - this is mainly for perf testing queries etc

Comment: I actually ended up doing something similar to this. Hooking into the tests with beforeEach and removing all collections in the DB and repopulating them all for each entity. But storing the  functionality required in a separate file for code organisation.

Comment: Sounds good, unit tests should run independently and setup and tear down what's needed for the test. It's worth learning a few of the bulk loading tools from the relevant databases. good luck with the rest of the project